# how to give equal spacing on entire html page

Tags: html, css

I have a structure which has some parent elements and beneath it some child elements, all of them have checkboxes.

I want to give equal spacing between parent and child checkboxes.

It currently looks like this :

[image]

I would like to have all the checkboxes aligned to the right.

My code is:

```
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat-start="filter in Filters">
                <td>
                    {{name}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fa fa-lg" ng-class="{'fa-check-square-o' : isFilterSelected(filter), 'fa-square-o' : !isFilterSelected(filter)}" ng-click="toggleFilter(filter)"></i>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat-end>
                <td ng-if="filter.subFilters.length > 0" colspan="2">
                    <ul style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                        <li ng-repeat="subFilter in filter.subFilters">
                            <div>
                                 <span style="
                                   width: 418px;
                                   display: inline-block;
                                   position: relative;">{{subFilter.name}}</span>
                                <span> <i class="fa fa-lg" ng-class="{'fa-check-square-o' : isFilterSelected(subFilter), 'fa-square-o' : !isFilterSelected(subFilter)}" style="padding: 5px;" ng-click="toggleFilter(subFilter)"></i></span>
                                <!--This is the child checkbox which i need to space same like parent -->
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: include a code snippet in your question that produces your current layout

Comment: use display flex and justify-content: space-between; on line wrapper

Comment: Don't right-pad your elements and align checbox to right

Comment: I have edited my span tag now they all are coming aligned, the issue I am still facing is: When i check a checkbox their position gets little disturbed. Is there any way they all remain aligned irrespective to check/uncheck.?

Comment: @Nick i tried your solution and applied the style on div wrapping the line and used margin-left with it to adjust the positioning. But the issue I am facing is the checkboxes dislocate a bit upon check/uncheck

Comment: Can you please suggest how to handle the positioning upon check/uncheck the check boxes